# TomTom GO & Ubuntu Linux: impersonating a GPRS phone with dund

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, tomtom

**Background:**

I've called TomTom support, and they don't support Linux.

I **can** get my GO 730 to mount Mass Storage, and I found a shell script that will allow me to install maps (haven't tried it; will update when I do.). As of note: USB 2.0 only. 1.1 ports will **not** work.

However--I still can't update the TomTom or take advantage of any traffic services. The GO will connect to a mobile phone, but I don't have one that supports tethering.

However, I've found a site that claims to know a way to get a [Linux Machine to impersonate a phone advertising GPRS services](http://www.fenrus.org/tomtom/) and it apparently works in Fedora as old as FC4.

I'm having some serious trouble getting this to work on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic, mainly because I think some of the built-in bluetooth stuff is getting in the way.

Changing the class bits in `main.conf` (`hcid.conf` does not exist) doesn't crash..., and `dund` starts and listens, but the TomTom device never seems to want to connect to my machine.

I haven't played around much with `sdcptool` (I think that's the name, not in front of a Linux machine right now) but maybe I have to advertise the DUN profile...I'm not very sure.

**My Question:**

I have no way to diagnose the problems. What are some diagnostic tools I can use to help dig down and figure out what's going on?

**Update**: apparently `dund` is a legacy tool that's going away. What replaces it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: return the device to retailer you purchased it from, and cut your losses.

I was not happy paying the sum I did for features that required TomTom home, such as the daily traffic updates, map sharing, and daily fuel prices.

I'll get a GPS that's better supported under GNU/Linux.

Comment: Do update this when you find one...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I could help with the GPRS setup, but...

1. Did you try TomTom Home with [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)?  My TomTom attached on WXP(SP2) without any unusual software, so I suspect the GO-730 is different.
2. Can you describe the symptoms when trying to mount as a mass-storage device?  For example, what are the outputs of `usbview` and `lspci`?  Are there corresponding `dmesg` entries?

Comment: The mass storage device issue has been solved. I'll update my question.

I'll try TomTom home with wine tonight, I sort of wanted to not use it.